# How do I store data in my android app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm very new to Android Developing.  I made a small 2d game and I was wondering what the easiest way to store the high-score would be, so if the app is exited and returned to the high-score is retrieved from the last session.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Also see [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Answer (score 7):

For a simple piece of data such as high score you could easily save this in SharedPreferences. This is a simple key value pairing that persists across app launches and doesn't require a SQL database.

To obtain a shared preference:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences( "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To edit and save to shared preference:

```
int highScore = 100; prefs.edit().putInt("HighScore", highScore).apply();
```

To retrieve shared preference :

```
int score = prefs.getInt("HighScore", 0);
```